# successCallback is not a function

Tags: javascript, binary

Can someone tell me why I'm getting `successCallback is not a function` in my js?

This is the code for calling it:

```
function fillData(data){
        this.raw = data;
    }

function AnimatedModel(posx, posy, posz,sx,sy,sz,r,g,b,a, name, yd){
        this.x = posx;
        this.y = posy;
        this.z = posz;
        this.scale = new Array(sx,sy,sz);
        parseBinFile(this, name)
        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
        this.a = a;
        this.yawDeg = yd;
        this.fillData = fillData;
    }

    var zombie = new AnimatedModel(0,0, 0, 0.2,0.2,0.2, 0.0,1.0,0.6,0.2, "zom3.ms3d", 0);

function parseBinFile(model, name){
        getServerFileToArrayBufffer(name, model.fillData)
        console.log(model.raw);

    }


    function getServerFileToArrayBufffer(url, successCallback){
            // Create an XHR object
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE) {
                if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.response) {
                        // The 'response' property returns an ArrayBuffer
                        successCallback(xhr.response);
                    } else {
                        alert("Failed to download:" + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Open the request for the provided url
            xhr.open("GET", url, true);
            // Set the responseType to 'arraybuffer' for ArrayBuffer response
            xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
            xhr.send();
        }
```

Edit: forgot the fillData function.

Comment: Well where does that "fillData" value come from?  That's what you're passing as "successCallback". It seems that it's the thing that's not a function.

Comment: I merely forgot it. Same error as before.

Comment: `successCallback` is not a function. (At the point `getSever..` is called `model.fillData` evaluates to *undefined* because the property is not set until *after* `parseBinFile` is called so thus `successCallback` is *undefined*: JavaScript is *strictly evaluated*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `parseBinFile()` in the `AnimatedModel` constructor before you set the `fillData` property in `AnimatedModel` so if that's the call that is causing you the problem, then you need to fully initialize the `AnimatedModel` object BEFORE you call `parseBinFile(this, name)`.

Comment: @pst - where?  The `fillData()` function in the code the OP has included is not a method on any object - it's just a standalone function.

Comment: `this.fillData = fillData` (after the call to `parseBinFile(this..)`, though). This issue likely from confusion of evaluation order.

Comment: @pst - maybe.  But the OP doesn't disclose the rest of the code that shows how that's actually used, called before it's used, etc...  And, I think it's a really confusing coding style to use the same names for functions and instance variables as it just confuses the heck out of readers.

Comment: I updated my answer.  I think the issue is that you are calling parseBinFile() before you've fully initialized the object you are passing it.